# SQL Server Pivot Rows Into Columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I've had look at the various SQL Server Pivot questions asked, but I have been unable to implement the various solutions to my particular example. I wonder if someone can provide me with the correct SQL syntax to allow me to transpose my rows into columns.

I have the following table:

```
Tutor_Event_ID  Tutor_FAN       Tutor_Individual_ID     Tutor_Title         Tutor_First_Name        Tutor_Last_Name     
59220           56004633        46415                   Mr                  Michael                 Brian                           
59220           67693357        128376                  Mr                  John                    Newtons
```

...and I want to transpose the info to look like this:

```
Tutor_Event_ID  First_Tutor_FAN         First_Tutor_Individual_ID       First_Tutor_Title           First_Tutor_First_Name      First_Tutor_Last_Name       Second_Tutor_FAN        Second_Tutor_Individual_ID      Second_Tutor_Title          Second_Tutor_First_Name     Second_Tutor_Last_Name      
59220           56004633                46415                           Mr                          Michael                     Brian                       67693357                128376                          Mr                          John                        Newtons
```

The challenge here is I need to transpose more than 1 field across, and I don't know all the possible values that these columns would hold, but essentially it's having one row per Event with the Tutor (or Tutors) info listed on the same row.
Can anyone please suggest an SQL Code to do this?

Many thanks in advance,
Veronica

Comment: Thanks for helping out with the formatting, not sure why it initially showed up like that. Looks a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the following example, wish is helpful

```
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
        CREATE TABLE #t(Tutor_Event_ID INT ,Tutor_FAN VARCHAR(100),Tutor_Individual_ID INT,Tutor_Title VARCHAR(100),Tutor_First_Name VARCHAR(100),Tutor_Last_Name VARCHAR(100))
        INSERT INTO #t(Tutor_Event_ID,Tutor_FAN,Tutor_Individual_ID,Tutor_Title,Tutor_First_Name,Tutor_Last_Name)
        SELECT 59220,'56004633',46415,'Mr','Michael','Brian' UNION ALL
        SELECT 59220,'67693357',128376,'Mr','John','Newtons' 
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max),@col NVARCHAR(max)

        SELECT @col=ISNULL(@col+',[','[')+c.data_title+']'
        FROM (SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Tutor_Event_ID ORDER BY Tutor_FAN)) AS rn FROM #t) AS t
        CROSS APPLY(VALUES(t.rn+'_Tutor_FAN',CONVERT(VARCHAR,Tutor_FAN)),(t.rn+'_Tutor_Individual_ID',CONVERT(VARCHAR,Tutor_Individual_ID)),(t.rn+'_Tutor_Title',Tutor_Title),(t.rn+'_Tutor_First_Name',Tutor_First_Name),(t.rn+'_Tutor_Last_Name',Tutor_Last_Name)) c(data_title,data_value)

        SET @sql='
        SELECT * FROM (
           SELECT t.Tutor_Event_ID,c.data_title,c.data_value
           FROM (SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Tutor_Event_ID ORDER BY Tutor_FAN)) AS rn FROM #t) AS t
           CROSS APPLY(VALUES(t.rn+''_Tutor_FAN'',CONVERT(VARCHAR,Tutor_FAN)),(t.rn+''_Tutor_Individual_ID'',CONVERT(VARCHAR,Tutor_Individual_ID)),(t.rn+''_Tutor_Title'',Tutor_Title),(t.rn+''_Tutor_First_Name'',Tutor_First_Name),(t.rn+''_Tutor_Last_Name'',Tutor_Last_Name)) c(data_title,data_value)
        ) n PIVOT(MAX(data_value) FOR data_title IN ('+@col+')) p
        '
        EXEC(@sql)
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
```

the following is the result:

```
Tutor_Event_ID  1_Tutor_FAN 1_Tutor_Individual_ID   1_Tutor_Title   1_Tutor_First_Name  1_Tutor_Last_Name   2_Tutor_FAN 2_Tutor_Individual_ID   2_Tutor_Title   2_Tutor_First_Name  2_Tutor_Last_Name
59220   56004633    46415   Mr  Michael Brian   67693357    128376  Mr  John    Newtons
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created a supported table(Numbers) which will have the column like 
num and word (1, first)
[image]